# Java Swing White Gap Under Title Bar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I am creating a simple Java GUI with Swing and I have a white bar that appears under the title bar that I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of. I appreciate any help and tips as I have searched all over for anyone with a similar problem and have not been able to find anything. Thanks

Image of Java GUI:

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/vdo7ju37b/image.png]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ja {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("jA");
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            f.setSize(400, 600);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JLabel bg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("brown.jpg"));
            bg.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            p.add(bg);

            JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");
            JButton b2 = new JButton("b2");
            JButton b3 = new JButton("b3");

            bg.add(b1);
            bg.add(b2);
            bg.add(b3);

            f.add(p);

            f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `JLabel` to act as background for other components, while it works, may not always result in the best outcome, as it does not calculate it's required sizing hints from the contents, but from the image and text properties of the label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A FlowLayout uses a gap of 5 pixels between the border of the parent container and the child components.

You can either:

1. Use a `FlowLayout`, but set this gap to 0 pixels. Read the FlowLayout API to see the constructor parameters for this.
2. Use a `BorderLayout` on your panel.